# ERC721 exchange logic

Tags: solidity, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

I'm trying to allow NFT holders to sell their tokens by listing prices (ETH) and allow others to buy those listed tokens.

I used openzeppelin and succesfully implemented and tested my token creation. Now, if I want that exchange to be happened, how do I further implement? I created another contract btw to begin with.

```
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol";

contract MyTokenSale {

 ERC721Token public token;

 constructor(address _tokenAddress) public {
    token = ERC721Token(_tokenAddress);
  }
```

Any examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the [0xcert](https://docs.0xcert.org/) framework that is made for managing erc721 tokens. You already have a build in exchange, erc721 creation, transfer etc and there are [tutorials available](https://github.com/MoMannn/ethereum-example/) for everything. Plus you don't need to know anything about solidity.

If you want to do it yourself you should checkout their [smart contracts](https://github.com/0xcert/framework/tree/master/packages/0xcert-ethereum-order-gateway-contracts) for exchange on which you can base your token selling.

Otherwise the basic concept if you want to sell a NFT for ETH would be.

- Create NFT (make sure only you can create it)
- Set price in ETH for specific NFT (for its id)
- Create a payable function that accepts id as parameter
- Check if the id is really for sale
- Check if the amount of eth sent is enough
- remove from you selling list (you have to do thins before doing any transfers to avoid a reentry attack)
- transfer the token
- transfer eth to your wallet

Answer (score 0):

You could list your tokens for sale on [OpenSea](https://opensea.io) without creating a sale contract.

To create your own token sale contract you could look at OpenZeppelin crowdsale contracts for inspiration, though these are for ERC20 (fungible, rather than ERC721 non-fungible).
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/crowdsales